# How to write big arrays/dataframe in your code

Tags: python, arrays, database

Another question from a beginner programmer... In my code I some data that is "pre-setted", and it will only be read once. For my case I believe a dataframe would fit better; however I will face the same "problem" having a huge dataframe.

Here is an example:

```
Sheet_thickness = [2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 12, 1, 2.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 1, 10, 12, 20,22, 25, 3, 6, 12, 15, 20, 50, 6, 12, 20, 75, 6, 12, 20, 101, 12, 6, 10, 11, 12, 8, 10, 11, 12, 20, 12, 25, 50, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 8, 10, 4, 6, 3, 12, 5, 15,
                   8, 6, 2, 10, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1.5, 6]
```

I don't believe this is the best way to write the arrays.

I don't work at any "programming company", but I want a clean code, that follows some "programming rules". I would really like to know how the big techs do this.

I am expecting to know how to write some big data in my code.

I tried to do what I showed above an it works perfectly, but I don't beleive that this is the best way to do this simple task.

Overall I want to know what is the best way to write arrays/dataframe for a "clean code"

Comment: For truly large data, you load it from a structured data file, such as a CSV file or whatever format suits your input data best.

Comment: you're asking for opinions which are not "on-topic" questions. but you want to store data. and for clean code, read [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) (no caps in variable names)

Comment: "...and it will only be read once..."    So say we all until reality hits...